# Webscrape html table data that has multiple images in a cell, I wish to take the attribute Title value in case the table has images

Tags: html, r

Trying to scrape the data from html table,

If the table has images,it is read as NA. I am able to read individually the image titles

This is the code i tried

```
weburl<- "https://www.transfermarkt.com/premier-
    league/transfers/wettbewerb/GB1/plus/?
    saison_id=2017&s_w=&leihe=0&leihe=1&intern=0&intern=1"


webcontent<-NULL
webcontent<-read_html(weburl)
table_text<-webcontent %>%
html_nodes(".responsive-table table") %>%
html_table()

###I am able to pull the Nationality individually but this could not be joined, as one Player could have two possible values

nationality_text<-webcontent %>%
 html_nodes(".responsive-table table td.zentriert.nat-transfer-cell img") %>%
 html_attr("title")
```

Can anyone help me get the Titles of the images in the table? currently using Rvest package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hack your way around with `xml2` package (already loaded by `rvest`).

I grab all `img` nodes for each flag and replace their text with their `title` attribute, with a semicolon separator. 
The text is then picked up by `html_text` when you convert the tables to data.frame.

(Notice that this is not valid XHTML, but it works with `rvest`: the text is not even exported to HTML).

```
# Get flags using XPath
node_flags <- tables %>% 
   xml_find_all("//td[contains(@class, 'nat-transfer-cell')]/img")
countries <- node_flags %>% 
   xml_attr('title')

node_flags %>% 
   xml_set_text(paste0(countries, ';'))

# Resume extraction
table_text <- tables %>%
   html_table()
```

Nationalities will be in column `Nat.`:

```
> table_text[[1]] %>% head
                        Arrivals Age              Nat.           Position Pos  Market value Moving from Moving from  Transfer fee
1         Álvaro MorataÁ. Morata  24          Germany;     Centre-Forward  CF 40,00 Mill. €          NA Real Madrid 62,00 Mill. €
2    Tiemoué BakayokoT. Bakayoko  22 DR Congo;England; Defensive Midfield  DM 16,00 Mill. €          NA      Monaco 40,00 Mill. €
3  Danny DrinkwaterD. Drinkwater  27          Albania;   Central Midfield  CM  9,00 Mill. €          NA   Leicester 37,90 Mill. €
4      Antonio RüdigerA. Rüdiger  24  England;England;        Centre-Back  CB 25,00 Mill. €          NA     AS Roma 35,00 Mill. €
5 Davide ZappacostaD. Zappacosta  25           Greece;         Right-Back  RB  8,50 Mill. €          NA      Torino 25,00 Mill. €
6         Ross BarkleyR. Barkley  24        Australia; Attacking Midfield  AM 25,00 Mill. €          NA     Everton 16,90 Mill. €
```